# How to set up sqlite fts in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a table with 5 columns. Two of them are text. I want to use fts for these two columns.
Do I have a fts table with all 5 columns or just the two columns, how do I set this up?

Note: I am shipping my own database not creating one from code.

Comment: This is all explained in the documentation: http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Lets Start DBMS
       For Create table : `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE book USING fts4 (id, author, title, excerpt);`
Select  Table:
       SELECT * FROM book WHERE excerpt MATCH 'best NEAR worst';
Insert int table:
       INSERT INTO pages(rowid, docid, title, body) VALUES(1, 2, 'A title', 'A document body');
```

> For more Refer this link
>   1.http://www.phparch.com/2011/11/full-text-search-with-sqlite/ 2.http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: how would i be using query() in android for querying result?? Sorry but i am noob at this. i need to see some code.

Comment: using it like i would use a normal sqlite table. but how can i use things like `MATCH`. but now i have a another problem. I mentioned i was copying the database from assets when application first launches (cause it is already pre-populted with loads of data) and it's throwing an io exception when i made the tables virtual. it worked fine before. Don't know if they are related